# Handlebars append css file to layout

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

Is there any way to append page specific css/js to layout in handlebars? I am able to do that with [block](http://www.learnjade.com/tour/block-append-and-prepend/) in jade. I am using Express with handlebars engine, there is main layout and base js/css files. For some pages, i need to add specific js or css files and couldn't handle to do that with handlebars.

Comment: Check out Grunt for handling your asset pipeline: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15302221/614152

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't want to use third party item. I just want to do that core handlebars. I was able to do that with Jade